# Desperately seeking better support for tagged searches

Tags: feature-request, tags

My interests on SO are relatively narrow and so I have to resort to tagged search to find questions I might wish to read or answer.  Lately I'm finding that traffic has gotten so large that even with tags it is difficult for me to find interesting questions.  I'd like better tools for using tags to browse questions.

Here's a specific feature request:

- If I do an **or** search on a large number of tags (13 is typical for me), along with the results screen I get some buttons, each of which takes me to questions tagged with that single tag.  **I'd like to have the dual feature**: that is, I'd like to be able to click on an 'x' next to a button and remove that tag from my search, so that I am now looking at results for the remaining 12 tags.  For example, if I search for questions tagged

  > functional-programming or  haskell or  lua or  ocaml or  caml or  c or  memory-management or  polymorphism or  lambda or  lambda-calculus or  compiler or  hardware or  teaching

  then I'd like to be able to click an 'x' next to the `c` button can get questions tagged

  > functional-programming or  haskell or  lua or  ocaml or  caml or memory-management or  polymorphism or  lambda or  lambda-calculus or  compiler or  hardware or  teaching

  and so on.

It probably makes sense for some kind reader or some energetic person on the SO team to think about more tools for navigating the high-dimensional tag space effectively.  Not my bailiwick, but I feel like it's getting harder and harder to find interesting questions, and my participation is dropping.  I'm still in the top 75 users based on reputation, but that's primarily a long tail of votes for old answers—I'm having trouble finding new questions I want to answer.

Comment: Downvoted because you don't want the feature?  You don't want me to have the feature?  I shouldn't have tagged a question both feature-request and discussion?  Help me out here...

Comment: Perhaps downvoted because it sounds like a personal ad? :-)

Comment: -1 - needs more images w/ drop-shadows and hand-drawn circles.

Comment: Thanks John for the edit.  5K rep on meta?  I'm in awe...

Comment: Looks like Facted Search to me. A quick drop-in of Solr ...