# Create a "questions that you can answer" page

Tags: feature-request, questions, answers

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How to find the right questions that I can answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44739/how-to-find-the-right-questions-that-i-can-answer)
>   [Tab for interesting questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11563/tab-for-interesting-questions)

I have a dream of having a page showing just the questions that I can answer. Such a page would be implemented with some weird, out-of-space algorithm; perhaps it could be tag-based. Can such a page be created?

Comment: I have a dream.  A user searching for [existing answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44739/how-to-find-the-right-questions-that-i-can-answer) before firing off a new question.  Sadly, my dreams never come true.  In the meantime, you might want to subscribe to some tags.

Comment: Eh, this isn't quite a dupe; the other question is a user asking how he can use SO more effectively, while this one is asking SO, Inc. to implement a question/answerer matching service.

Comment: It is called a 'blog'.

Comment: This is the [feature-request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11563/tab-for-interesting-questions) you want, but it doesn't look like it will be implemented anytime soon.  You can upvote it to keep it moving though.

Comment: I search for existing answers first, but it doesn't seem to be the same answers. I am thinking in a more personalized page, like AArdvark (http://vark.com/) the webpage informs you when some question can be YOUR question.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to Meta, Mahomedalid! Unfortunately, I don't think this is in the cards. A "questions you can answer" page would have to take into consideration what you do and do not know, what questions are asking for — at a more fine-grained level than what tags often provide — and possibly your level of expertise and the question's difficulty. Question difficulty ratings have been proposed before, but always declined, largely because there's no good objective measure we can use. In short, **there just isn't enough information available for such an algorithm to work**.

That said, I'd be happy to be proven wrong; do you have a suggestion for the sort of algorithm that could be used?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Google Chrome, you could try the [Stacked Odds](https://stackapps.com/questions/1141/stacked-odds-finding-the-questions-that-you-can-answer) extension.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried that big "[Unanswered](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/unanswered)" link you can find in every page?

It only shows questions with no upvoted answers in the tags you have set as interesting. :)

Comment: Yes, I have tried, but there are questions answered where I can put a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use tags. I've found that I'm more likely to nail the jQuery answers now that I've got the visual indicator of that type of question.