# How do SO'ers select questions to answer?

Tags: discussion, questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find the right questions that I can answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44739/how-to-find-the-right-questions-that-i-can-answer)

I am new to Stack Overflow so this might be an oft repeated question. Nothing turned up in my search, so here goes:

I am curious about what different methods people use to select questions to answer. I want to adopt a suitable strategy for myself. Do people take a look at a few regular places such as unanswered, active, hot, etc. or some tag of interest?

My main concern is that with the high rate of question submission good questions may get buried too fast. It is obvious to me that Stack Overflow goes a long way to make it incredibly easy for someone to ask a question, but does it work the same way for answering questions too?

Sub question: does Stack Overflow accept user contributed features?

Comment: Ignore my subquestion. I just learnt about stackapps.My original question turned out to be a duplicate after all http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44739/how-to-find-the-right-questions-that-i-can-answer I didnt find it in my initial search. Honest.

Comment: welcome to MSO! Thanks for following up with that dupe link. I've voted to close on principle, but don't worry about it too much, it happens to us all sometimes, and you're obviously conscientious about it.

Comment: Thanks for the answers and the edit. I didnt realise it was that badly formed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What most people do is they follow a certain set of tags on which they are the best at. There are 2 good ways to see the newest question of the tags you want to follow.

The first one is to add interesting tag and just browser the recent question in the `Active` tab or the `Newest` tab.

The second one is to get the list of the question for a tag. Each tag has his own page where you can see the newest question, featered question, etc. The URL for those page is the following :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/TagNameHere

You can also use that feature to browser question with a group of tag. If you want to follow question about Javascript, that are only about jQuery you can use this URL :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript+jquery

The advantage with the second option is that questions stay for a couple of hour on those page for popular tag and even more when they are about very specific technology.

Answer (score 1):

For low-rate type of questions, say tagged with `forth`, it is useful to use the [RSS feed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSS) (there is a link on the tag page's lower right, for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/forth).

It can also be used for higher rate type of questions, but the RSS reader needs to be able to properly handle it to not drown out other feeds. There is also delay in notification, a problem in the highly competitive tags, say `c#`.