# Where can I find questions to which I might know an answer?

Tags: support, tags, questions

Is there any short way of seeing questions that I could possibly answer?
(e.g., based on the tags of my own questions or something)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find the right questions that I can answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44739/how-to-find-the-right-questions-that-i-can-answer)

Answer (score 1):

The [SO homepage](https://stackoverflow.com/) uses a weighted algorithm to try to focus on unanswered questions that you are likely to be able to answer.  It places priority on Favorite Tags (can be added via the upper right corner of the homepage) and tags which you have provided good answers for in the past.

See [this blog entry](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/stack-overflow-homepage-changes/) for an explanation of the actual algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, click on the "Unanswered" link at the top of the page.

Comment: not exactly what i wanted, i wanted a seaarch that gives me question with more then tag i used, something like sorting by the number of tags i used

Answer (score 0):

Click on one of the tags you think that you know something about and on the tag navigation tabs click on `Unanswered`.

Alternatively you can build your URL like this.

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/TAG-OF-INTEREST?sort=unanswered
```

Comment: not exactly what i wanted, i wanted a seaarch that gives me question with more then tag i used, something like sorting by the number of tags i used