# Where can I find unanswered questions asked by beginners?

Tags: discussion

I am a beginner my self, so I can't answer many questions myself. I would like to know where to find the easiest questions so I can answer.

Comment: You're not likely to ever find such a query.  You can't really tell if someone is a "beginner" by looking at the information that is available on the sites about the users.  You'll just have to watch the tags that you are comfortable with like a hawk and try to get some answers in.

Comment: This is a common issue with no good answer. For hard questions, the experts are the only ones who know how to answer, so you're out of luck. For easy questions, the experts still know how to answer, and they usually do it faster and/or better than everyone else, so... you're __still__ out of luck.

Comment: Somewhat related.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44739/how-to-find-the-right-questions-that-i-can-answer

Answer (score 11):

Jeff and Popular are both addressing the issue from the [Fastest Gun In The West](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem) perspective with *try to get some answers in* and *and they usually do it faster and/or better than everyone else*.

Both raise very good points but there's another way to find questions than surfing the newest questions: [surf the old questions](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/?page=15&tab=mytags). If you start about fifteen pages into the "unanswered questions" list, you'll find there are plenty of questions with only one or two answers -- and the answers on that list have no upvotes, so they might not be very good. If you've populated your "favorite tags" list with technologies you're familiar with, it'll be easy to skim through the list looking for highlighted questions with no answers or few answers, and find ones that you might be able to improve drastically. You might also find that the answers aren't *good* answers, and ought to be downvoted or flagged as Not An Answer -- or the questions are unanswered because they are *bad* questions and need to be flagged as Very Low Quality, Not a Real Question, etc.

Comment: One should not forget about the possibility that there are also questions that are just bad. While users are at digging through those lists they can also flag such bad questions.

Answer (score 6):

@PopularDemand is right, getting started can be tough.

I got comfortable with StackOverflow by starting in a technology I was comfortable with and then moving to a less-frequented tag for a library or plugin belonging to the technology.

For example, say you're comfortable with [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery). That's a pretty popular tag with lots of experts. Starting out there might be pretty intimidating. Instead, start out in tags like [jquery-validate](/questions/tagged/jquery-validate) or [jqueryui](/questions/tagged/jqueryui) (this strategy applies to most every major tag out there).

There are several advantages of "working up to" a tag like this:

1. You can take your time when answering. Which means you can provide high-quality, working answers that will almost *always* be accepted.
2. You're still helping people out, and that's what its all about right?
3. Eventually you'll get so comfortable answering in auxiliary tags that you'll be quick enough and expert enough (after all, the tags you were answering under were just a subset of the "master" tag you were aiming at) to answer questions in the main tag.

Basically, find a nice corner of StackOverflow and make it your own.

Comment: This is, in fact, precisely what tag subscriptions and digests were developed for. You don't even have to visit the site on a regular basis. Just subscribe to a handful of niche tags, sit back and wait. And if you can't help anyone else with *any* niche tags, if the *only* questions you can answer are dumb-dumb beginner "how do I write a loop in C#" questions, then you need to go out into the world and actually learn something before you can earn any reputation.