# Reliable paging

Tags: discussion, feature-request, navigation

Stack Overflow is high volume Q&A site. So it happens regularly that when I read the last question and press the button to see next page, I see the same questions again, because there are plenty of new questions.

Please add some kind of key of the first "next" question to the paging URLs, so they will display next questions only.

Comment: Well, it is annoying from user experience perspective. I press Next page to see next questions, not the same question on current page.

Comment: The solution is to read faster than the rate of incoming new questions. :)

Comment: Then it will become questions without answear site :-)

Comment: @LeosLiterak hmm currently StackOverflow [has a 77% answer rate](http://stackexchange.com/sites#traffic) so I don't think the without answer site is really true. I think perhaps you should change how you're using the site for example you might want take advantage of the tag filtering.

Comment: that was kind of joke in reaction that I shall click next page so fast like new questions arise

Comment: @LeosLiterak I guessed I missed the ":-)". In any case you might want to check out [How to find the right questions that I can answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/44739/148672) rather then using the home page

Comment: great link, I did not have an idea how powerfull SO search is. Great job

Answer (score 4):

Step 1:  Click the Questions button
Step 2:  Scroll to bottom of page
Step 3:  Ctrl-click on numbers 2-5
Step 4:  Enjoy 5 pages of fresh questions

Comment: Wrong. Step 2: ????, Step 3: Profit!

Comment: Or fix it - URL for previous page: ?action=back&last=123456, query will be and primaryKey<12346. Of course other pages cannot have this principle.